# Run RSpec for more than one Ruby version using single command

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I was looking for a way to run 'rake spec' for all ruby versions.

So far I wrote this code in Rakefile but it doesn't work:

```
RUBIES = ['ruby-2.0.0', 'ruby-2.1.1', 'ruby-2.2.1']

RUBIES.each do |ruby_v|
  sh "rvm use #{ruby_v}"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
end
```

Any ideas how may I accomplish this?

It would be great if I could pass down arguments specifying whether I want to run the tests for a single ruby version or for all.

**EDIT:**

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/e5599d112b3546a33b67ca35417462d4) the Rakefile I used and the error I am getting. It's not the same file which I mentioned at the top. It uses `rvm use #{ruby_v}; rspec spec` as suggested by Keith in the answer.

Comment: You can't switch the Ruby version from within Ruby.

Comment: Hmm. So, is there any way to write a rake task that would run specs for a number of different rubies?

Comment: RVM comes with [wrappers](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron#direct). According to the docs, running `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1@projectX/rake` should work (you have to adjust the path)

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks @Stefan. The plus point here is that I don't have to rely upon presence of `bash` or `zsh`. Also the output appears on screen as soon as it's generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rvm is a shell command and its Ruby setting applies only to the current instance of the shell.  So when you run `sh "rvm use #{ruby_v}"` you're changing the rvm version of the shell that you have invoked, and then exiting from that shell.

In addition, your Ruby program is an operating system process running the Ruby virtual machine, so when you make the call to `RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)`, you're still in that same OS process and Ruby version with which you started your script.

You'll need to run the rspec tests in the shell that you invoke and change the Ruby version on.  I thought something like this would work:

```
`rvm use #{ruby_v}; rspec spec`
```

...but as you pointed out, it does not. You need to run the new shell as a "login shell" so that rvm is set up correctly.  In addition, the new shell must be told that the thing you're invoking is a shell command and not a script or binary executable. In other words:

1) have your command explicitly invoke `bash` or `zsh` (`sh` did not work for me on my Mac).

2) specify (probably with `-l`) that it is a login shell.

3) specify (probably with `-c`) that you are executing a shell command (`rvm`) and not a script or executable.

I am using `zsh` as my shell, but you should be able to substitute `bash` in the code below and it should work (and of course put your rspec command in there):

```
2.3.0 :024 > puts `zsh -lc "rvm current"`
ruby-2.3.0
 => nil
2.3.0 :025 > puts `zsh -lc "rvm use jruby; rvm current"`
Using /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0
jruby-9.0.5.0
 => nil
2.3.0 :026 > puts `zsh -lc "rvm current"`
ruby-2.3.0
 => nil
```

Comment: I tried. I still get the error: `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.` using your suggestion and the ruby version isn't changing but yes the specs are running.

Comment: @Lokesh *"still"?* You didn't mention any errors. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Lokesh I've updated the (latter part of) the answer with what I think will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @KeithBennett this is what I was looking for. Further I was wondering if its possible to get the output as soon as it's generated because the `puts` print all the input at once.

Comment: You can process output as it is generated, but it's of course more complex.  Check out the `Open3` class.